# Is there an output log like Xcode's available locally in my iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am developing an iOS application and thanks to Xcode's "output log" I've been able to fix lots of bugs and such.

When I run my iOS application without Xcode, sometimes it crashes. However, it is hard to tell why did it crash since my device was not connected to Xcode. So I was wondering, when I run my iOS application, is there an output log like Xcode's stored somewhere within the iOS device I can retrieve? Or do I definitely need Xcode? Or perhaps there are other ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you connect your device to your computer, open up the Organizer in XCode. There will be a device log tab that you can select to view device & crash logs.

Answer (score 1):

Go in the organizer then on devices. You'll get logs in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are jailbroken you can use the syslog in /var/log/. I find it useful.

edit: You need to download syslogd to /var/log/syslog package on cydia also.